# For $f$ an analytic function, what is

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

$f$ be analytic function, could any one tell me how to find the value of $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\cos t \,\mathrm dt$$

I am not able to apply any complex analysis result here, could any one give me hint?

Comment: Does $\cos(t)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{it}+e^{-it})$ count?

Comment: I have no Idea ...

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a change of variables, $z = e^{it}$, which maps the interval $[0,2\pi]$ to the unit circle. You get

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\cos t\,dt &= \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) \frac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}{2} \,dt
\\
&=\int_{|z|=1} f(z) \frac{z+\frac1z}{2} \frac{dz}{iz} \\
&=\frac{1}{2i} \int_{|z|=1} f(z) \frac{z^2+1}{z^2}\,dz \\
&=\frac{1}{2i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}\,dz = \pi f'(0)
\end{align}
assuming $f$ is analytic on a neighborhood of the closed unit disc (using Cauchy's integral theorem and Cauchy's integral formula for $f'$).

Comment: The OP stated "I am not able to apply any complex analysis result(s) here"..

Comment: I read "not able" as "was unsuccessful", not "is artificially not allowed to". Since the only tag is complex-analyis, the second interpretation seems very strange.

Comment: I guess that does make more sense. here I was trying to prove that without using Cauchy's theorem :)